Is tipping your personal trainer considered weird in South India?
I'm on a long vacation (several months) in a medium sized town in Tamil Nadu, India. Recently I started going to a gym. I pay RS 3500 monthly for membership and unlimited personal trainer. Whenever I come I get a PT coach who offers me 1-1 training (not shared with other people.)
After small talking with people in the gym I know that his salary is not very high and most of the 3500 I pay goes to the gym owners and not to him.
I thought it might be a good idea to give him a rs 50 tip after each session. I might go as often as 20 times a month so this could be an addition to his salary of rs 1000 a month.
Would this be considered weird? Or could he get in trouble with gym management for it?
He's a 21 year old guy, living at home with his parents.

There's several cultural faux-pas you might end up committing here. And if his employer gets wind of your tipping, perhaps they will want a piece of the pie. Is it possible to transfer money digitally? See if you can get a response from someone who is local.

@MastaBaba Yes, I'm indeed looking for a response from someone local

As someone who goes to India frequently, I generally find that the custom is to give a larger sum at the end of your relationship. (A few thousand as a parting gift.) Not sure if that's the standard thing with personal trainers, though.

South Indian here.
Yes, it is considered weird. I haven't heard about tipping outside of restaurants (It is very much optional). Some may gladly accept it, others may reject outright. Gym owners may not like that.
However, a thoughtful gift such as a T-shirt or something is always acceptable. In most of the Indian culture, it is considered insulting the gift giver to reject a non-cash gift (cash gifts may be considered the opposite).

It certainly is not weird. However, if he is an employee of the gym, he may not be able to accept any form of payment (even tips) as part of his services, unless management allow tips (which I highly doubt).
Tipping culture is not as established in India as it is in other parts of the world. Tipping in restaurants is common, but for other services it depends on the owner of the establishment and the specific situation. You may check with the your trainer if he would be in any trouble if he accepts your tips. (Kindly, do not ask management as it may raise concerns of special treatment of individuals.)
If he cannot take tips, you can offer him a gift which I think will be accepted by the owner. You can give him gift cards or something else other than money.
